# How to create Stacked Line Chart in chartjs Multiple Y Axis and common X Axis

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, line, linechart

[image: Example Chart Image]

How can I create stacked chart in chartjs like in image?
But I want y2 axis to have 2x more height than other y scales.
I was able to create multiple y axis but cant set the height of any scale I want.

```js
  let scales = {
    x: {
      type: "linear",
      position: "left",
      max: res.maxs[0],
    },
    y: {
      type: "linear",
      position: "left",
      stack: "demo",
      stackWeight: 2,
      grid: {
        borderColor: colors.blue,
      },
      max: res.maxs[4],
      min: 0,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: titlesLabelY[3],
        font: {
          size: 11,
        },
      },
    },
    y2: {
      type: "linear",
      position: "left",
      stack: "demo",
      stackWeight: 2,
      grid: {
        borderColor: colors.blue,
      },
      max: res.maxs[3],
      min: 0,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: titlesLabelY[2],
        font: {
          size: 11,
        },
      },
      ticks: {
        callback: (value, index, values) => (index == (0)) ? undefined : value.toFixed(1),
      },
    },
  };
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the role of `stackWeight` (see the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-options-to-all-cartesian-axes)). The length of each axis in the same stack is proportional to its `stackWeight`.

So, if axis `y2` should have twice the length of `y` and `y3` (those two being equal) you should set  `stackWeight: 2` for `y2` and `stackWeight: 1` for the other two.

Here's a minimal example:

```js
const x = Array.from({length: 101}, (_, i)=>({x: i/100}));
const data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            data: x.map(({x})=>({x, y: Math.exp(x+1)})),
            borderColor: 'red',
        },
        {
            data: x.map(({x})=>({x, y: Math.exp(-x+1)})),
            borderColor: 'blue',
            yAxisID: 'y2',
        },
        {
            data: x.map(({x})=>({x, y: Math.sin(x+1)})),
            borderColor: 'green',
            yAxisID: 'y3',
        }
    ]
};
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
        },

        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'linear',
            },
            y: {
                stack: 'demo',
                offset: true,
                stackWeight: 1,
            },
            y2: {
                stack: 'demo',
                stackWeight: 2,
                offset: true,
                border: {
                    color: 'black',
                    width: 2
                }
            },
            y3: {
                stack: 'demo',
                offset: true,
                stackWeight: 1
            }
        }
    },
};
new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart1'), config);
```

```html
<canvas id="chart1" style="height:600px"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-CMF3tQtjOoOJoOKlsS7/2loJlkyctwzSoDK/S40iAB+MqWSaf50uObGQSk5Ny/gfRhRCjNLvoxuCvdnERU4WGg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```